# Which domain should the IP PTR record resolve to?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, ptr-record

I am trying to set up a mailserver alongside my webserver, `example.com`, at IP address `192.0.2.1`

- I have installed the usual suspects; Postfix, Dovecot, Roundcube,
  ClamAV milter, and OpenDKIM. I believe I have them all functioning.
- I have set A records for `example.com`
  and `mx.example.com` both pointing to `192.0.2.1`
- I set the MX record
  for `example.com` to point to `mx.example.com`
- I have made CNAMEs for `mail` and `smtp` pointing to `example.com`
- I set up an SPF record allowing `A` `MX` and rejecting everything else `-all`
- The SMTPd banner indentifies as `example.com`

Should the PTR for 192.0.2.1 resolve to `mx.example.com` or `mail.example.com` or `example.com` ?

More importantly, what determines which particular domain a PTR should resolve to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PTR` record is recommended (not required) to

- have a valid corresponding `A` record (against [SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch))

  > The forward lookup (A) of the hostname hostname did not match the reverse lookup (PTR) for the IP Address. Some receiving mail servers may use this as an indication of a possible spam source in a scoring system.  Most will not reject incoming mail solely on this basis.
- be the same as the one introduced in your SMTP banner (against [SMTP Banner Check](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-banner-check)).

  > Email servers answer connections on port 25 with a string of text called an SMTP Banner whose purpose is to announce the server and any information that the administrator would like to convey to the world.
  >
  > It is best practice to put the name of your server in your SMTP banner so that anybody who connects via your IP Address has a clue as to who they are talking to. You will get this warning if the name you present yourself as is not in the same domain as the hostname we get when we perform a PTR lookup on your IP Address.

If you can change the `PTR` record, the SMTP banner having `example.com`, this would be:

```
example.com.              IN   A    192.0.2.1
1.2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.   IN   PTR  example.com.
```

Notice that e.g. `mx.example.com` or `mail.example.com` would be ok too, as long as they all match.

If you can't change the `PTR` record, you can always change your SMTP banner to match the `PTR`. Even if your contract doesn't allow free `PTR` records, an ISP should have a matching `A`/`PTR` pair. If they don't, it wouldn't make a huge difference, as most won't reject mail solely on this basis.

---

As your question is about following best practices, there's one thing to fix: your PTR record. You currently have `"v=spf1 +a +mx -all"`. This requires additional DNS queries for `A` and `MX`.

- As you have everything on the same server, it's useless to have both `a` & `mx` listed.
- It's recommended to use direct [`ip4` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4), instead: `"v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.1 -all"`

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the +ip4 in the SPF. Right now we have a /27 that's kinda crowded, but if we can get an upgrade on that, I may actually segregate the mail and the web in the future. Pending progress delays on that I'll implement that suggestion in the meantime.

Comment: You may still use `ip4` as it also supports CIDR notation and multiple entries. :)